# How do I call the arrays name date and num

Tags: c#

Hi i was working on some code for class when i ran into a problem. I can't seem to call the array name num and date to main. I have to them in the method. And i need to call them to main so i can send them to another method right after. So basically what i am asking is how do i call the array to main and how will i send it to me next method?

```
 }
    public static void RArray(string[] name, string[] num, string[] date)
    {
        StreamReader infile = new StreamReader("data.txt");
        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("cards.txt");
        string[] fields = new string[50];
        string[] temp = new string[50];
        name = new string[50];
        num = new string[50];
        date = new string[50];
        string line, read;
        int i = 0;
--------code------
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            read = Convert.ToString(fields[j]);
            temp = read.Split(',');
            name[j] = temp[0];
            num[j] = temp[1];
            date[j] = temp[2];
            //Console.WriteLine(temp[0]);
            //Console.WriteLine(temp[1]);
            //Console.WriteLine(temp[2]);
        }
```

Comment: You did not paste the entire code.. and you are not clear enough what exactly it is you want. Do you want to be able to access the num[] and date[] arrays from your Main method, after you have called the RArray method?

Comment: yes and sorry the rest of the code is irrelevant. I just need to know how to pass those 3 arrays to main and store the values in 3 other arrays so i can start editing them in an other method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you structure out your program a bit differently, you are currently passing an argument to a method that does not actually need it, since you are always declaring a new array after the argument is passed anyway. Here is how it should look like and now you can actually use those arrays in your main function:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var name = new string[50];
    var num = new string[50];
    var date = new string[50];
    RArray(name, num, date);
    //do whatever with name, num, date arrays, you have modified them successfully
}

public static void RArray(string[] name, string[] num, string[] date)
{
    StreamReader infile = new StreamReader("data.txt");
    StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("cards.txt");
    string[] fields = new string[50];
    string[] temp = new string[50];

    string line, read;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        read = Convert.ToString(fields[j]);
        temp = read.Split(',');
        name[j] = temp[0];
        num[j] = temp[1];
        date[j] = temp[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i pass them to another method that actually does things to them?